# Something wrong with Hibernate DB connection pooler c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

since last post, did all the changes suggested but this problem still haunts me. Here's the error i get:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 44,499,102 milliseconds ago.
```

here's my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>        
    <property name="connection.autoReconnect"> true</property>
    <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
    <property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">150</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property> <!-- seconds --> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property> <!-- seconds --> 

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://!secret!autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">!secret!</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">!secret!</property>


    <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property> -->

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="mappings.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and c3p0.properties

```
c3p0.preferredTestQuery=select 1 from dual
c3p0.maxConnectionAge=3600
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin=true
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3p0.acquireRetryDelay=1000
c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=30
c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure=false
c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=100
```

Comment: just saw that feature now, checking answers in ...

Comment: ok, i did everything possible and i still get that horrid error message. Here's my hibernate configL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me, you're incorrectly configured c3p0.

Properties like c3p0.preferredTestQuery must be located at c3p0.properties file from your classpath (e.g. WEB-INF/classes).

Below is my example of c3p0.properties file that work nice for Oracle:

```
c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1 from dual
c3p0.maxConnectionAge=3600
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3p0.acquireRetryDelay=1000
c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=30
c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure=false
```

See also official doc for c3p0 [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html).

And please pay your attention to version of c3p0 that you're using. They had an issue connection restoring in early releases of c3p0 0.9.

Comment: Yes, +1. More specifically, check the [Hibernate specific instruction](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#hibernate-specific).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the connection to the database has timed out and has been terminated by the database server. You should either [increase the time the server can wait](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) or append ?autoReconnect=true to your jdbc connection string.

Comment: I had the ?autoReconnect=true before and it was not working. Also, note that i have <property name="connection.autoReconnect"> true</property> which should do the same ....

Answer (score 0):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554353/database-connection-to-mysql-times-out-even-after-setting-c3p0-testconnectiononc) might help. If it is the case, increasing the value of `wait_timeout` only postpones the ocurrence more time, rather than solving the problem.

The problem could be related with this:

- You open an hibernate session
- Do some things that take more time than the value of [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html) of your database
- You try to use this hibernate session. The message that you comment here will appear

I've documented a case in [here](http://www.supermanhamuerto.com/doku.php?id=java:thelastpacketsuccessfullyreceivedfromserver) if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the below line (1) in c3po.properties file  in your root  derectory.(you  should  used  hibenate-c3po 3.6.10 final.jar) And  in the Hibeanate.cfg.xml  used  add (2) part .

1. c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
2. `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
           <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">30</property>
           <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
           <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
           <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
           <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
           <property>`