# How to handle Database server failure while saving data using Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, postgresql-8.4

I have a web application which using PostgreSQL as database.

Assume the scenario like i am trying to Save() data using Hibernate. Now just before save the data if database server will down then what happened ?

Hibernate will re-try save again or do i have to write the re-try code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Hibernate will not re-try to save your data. The db failure will cause your transaction to fail, and all the change will be rollbacked.
Even worse, if you don't configure correctly your connection pool, you will not be able to re-establish the connection when the db will be running again. Take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083759/re-establishing-a-db-connection-after-a-network-failure-hibernate) for more info. I copy and paste c3p0 configuration.

```
<c3p0-config>
<default-config>
<!-- Configuring Connection     Testing -->
<!-- property name="automaticTestTable">TEST_EMS_HIBERNATE_CONN</property -->
<property name="checkoutTimeout">0</property>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">false</property>
<property name="preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1 from dual</property>
<!-- Configuring Recovery From Database Outages -->
<property name="acquireRetryAttempts">0</property>
<property name="acquireRetryDelay">1000</property>
<property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure">false</property>
<!-- Configuring to     Debug and Workaround Broken     Client Apps     -->
<property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout">1800</property>
<property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
</default-config>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already used c3p0 properties but not all attributes which you mentioned. I will try all attrs as you suggest.

Comment: @ManojKathiriya, you are welcome. Please, in case this is the solution for you, upvote/accept it (and maybe upvote the first answer in the link I provided)

Comment: AS of now i have configured as per suggestion given by you and not facing any issues.