# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I've developed an application and it worked just fine locally , and when I uploaded it to a remote server it gave me com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException. I've tried the solution mentioned in the topic in this link :

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565143/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operati#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565143/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operati#_=_)

here is the code that has access to database:

```
 protected Number getCount(Class clazz){
      Session currentSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
      return (Number) currentSession.createCriteria(clazz).setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
}
```

and here is my hibernate configuration:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property    name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lyrics_db</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
<!-- seconds -->
<property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
<!-- seconds -->

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and it's not working and I'm getting the same exception , and here is my full stack trace:

```
Dec 3, 2013 8:02:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
at daos.UltimateDao.listWithLimitWithOrder(UltimateDao.java:47)
at daos.LyricDao.getTopHundred(LyricDao.java:73)
at com.xeeapps.service.Service.getTopHundred(Service.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor127.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1290)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1282)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4468)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4434)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:1076)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:505)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:423)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
at    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
... 40 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 38,056,253 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 38,056,857 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3871)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2484)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:144)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:305)
at daos.UltimateDao.get(UltimateDao.java:24)
at daos.SongDao.getSong(SongDao.java:31)
at daos.LyricDao.getLyricForSong(LyricDao.java:24)
at com.xeeapps.service.Service.getLyricForASong(Service.java:82)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3852)
... 53 more
Dec 3, 2013 8:02:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET       http://localhost:8080/LyricsService/webresources/service/getTopHundred returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:686)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)
at client.LyricsClient.getTopHundred(LyricsClient.java:71)
at controllers.TopHundredController.init(TopHundredController.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2563)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2135)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Does anyone know why this exception keeps happening even I changed my configuration?

Comment: What's the connection timeout configured on your mysql?

Comment: My connection timeout on mysql is 8 hours.

Comment: The connection is over 10 hours old.  Your c3p0 settings need tweaking.  Try adding idle checks or expiring very old connections.

Comment: how can I check on expiring very old connections?

Comment: Share your data access code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something wrong with Hibernate DB connection pooler c3p0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842232/something-wrong-with-hibernate-db-connection-pooler-c3p0)

Comment: @dev.khafaga You also use c3p0 and have exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem was that I didn't commit the transaction , so it made some sort of lock.I figured this out from this topic:
[What happens if you don't commit transaction in a database (say SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896479/what-happens-if-you-dont-commit-transaction-in-a-database-say-sql-server)